# Triggering an application from a windows service cannot find file?

Tags: c#, .net, service

**Background:**
I created a service that will trigger the execution of an application when certain conditions have been met. This service is setup to run under the same windows user account that is used to log on to the system via RDP. I also created the .NET application that is trigger via this service. This application looks for a configuration file on disk (found in the ProgramData folder for the application) uses the settings found in the configuration file to affect the output of this application.

**Problem:**
When the application is ran by the user interactively the application runs great. However when the service triggers the application to run it appears that the application is not loading the correct values from the configuration files. It's almost as though the application when ran from a service has its own configuration file, and is not using the one found in ProgramData.

I'm just looking for some insight to why this may be happening. I have seem some odd behavior from Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 when running applications via scheduled tasks or as a service. It's almost like interactive applications and service applications have different environments on the same system running as the same user...

**Note:** The service executable is also found in the same folder as the triggered application. I would expect that the working directory by default would be the services running directory.

```
  public int ExecRun()
  {
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
       FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\TEST\\runme.exe",
       Arguments = "/DS:TEMP"
    };

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();

    return proc.ExitCode;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to execute the app? you probably need to specify the execution folder.

Comment: Update to show how we are calling the application from the service. We are not specifying the working directory. Wouldn't that default the services running directory?  I should also note that this phenomenon does not occur on every installation.

Comment: No, it depends on OS and other things

Comment: First, are you using the App.Config file?  Second, are the settings scoped to the user?  Third, if you look in the Event log, do you see any instances where it mentions logging into a temp profile?

Comment: We are not using the app.config file. The settings are system wide.

Comment: Are there multiple configuration files in the same directory?  Is it possible the code has a piece laying around directing it at another config file that was used for testing or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the working directory info:

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\TEST\\runme.exe",
            WorkingDirectory="C:\\Program Files\\TEST",
            Arguments = "/DS:TEMP"
        };
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue. I suspect the issue is being caused by a corrupt user profile on the system. When the software being ran via the service attempts to find the file "C:\\ProgramData\\Test\\configuration.xml" it appears to be getting a version of the file that is different that what actually exists there...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the service that triggers the execution of the application also needs to set the working directory.  If you're using the `Process` class, you'll need to set the `StartInfo.WorkingDirectory` property the path where your application resides.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.

Unfortunately, I think I wasted all your time with this question. The users is running this service on a second system (other than the one they claimed was having this issue). They copied the same configuration to both systems which would've been fine if they had setup both systems the same way, but alas they did not. The file did not exist on the system throwing the error, but both systems were setup to log exceptions to the same location.

The user had to disable the second service, or setup the configuration file correctly.